# UITextView height won't change

Tags: ios, objective-c

I don't know why, but when I try to change the height of a UITextView there is no change at all.

```
CGRect frame = self.descView.frame;
frame.size.height = 500; 
self.descView.frame = frame;
```

I have created the UITextView from storyboard and I used fixed height.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using autolayout?

Comment: Yes I am using autolayout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your textview height using create an instance of height constraint of textview.

from storyboard first right click on height constraint of textview and create instance in class file like below

```
@IBOutlet var textviewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

then,  easily you can play with its height

```
textviewHeight.constant = 500
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
```

Comment: I do right click on height constraint and nothing happens

Comment: first select constraint. means just click on it when it is highlight then right click

Answer (score 0):

If there are no autolayout conflicts the following code should set the correct height.

```
self.descView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 500).isActive = true
```

Comment: Property 'constraint' not found on object of type 'NSLayoutDimension *'

Comment: I recommend you to check the documentation. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutdimension